# How to run script on each xterm window in mininet automatically?

Tags: xterm, mininet

I am new on mininet and SDN. I want to generate random traffic in mininet, say from each host.
So I can run:

```
sudo mn -x
```

Then, h1 and h2 will pop up, so I can run manually:

```
./script.sh
```

in each xterm window.

However, if I have 100 hosts(so 100 windows will pop up), it's not feasible to run them manually.
So how could we run them automatically? (i.e. when 100 windows pop up, they can run their scripts automatically)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mininet CLI api` to run automated scripts instead of xterm. Please have a look at the similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50094021/6044878)